# Read all contacts from phone and sim Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

EDIT ::: The code works. It was a problem with Eclipse, and the code displays the output in logcat as intended.

Android 2.3.3

I am pretty new to using contentproviders. I just want to try out an example of how to retrieve contacts from my phone. I have seen few examples, but none worked for me, when I tried it over my SAMSUNG Mobile.

Here is the code that i have used...

```
public class Class_Add_Contact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);

        readContacts();    
    }

    private void readContacts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            String name =cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));    
            String phoneNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            System.out.println(name + "   " + phoneNumber);
            }
    }
}
```

The code seems fine, but there aren't any numbers displayed in the logcat. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    System.out.println(contactId + "   " + name);
}
cursor.close();
```

it returns the contact's name and the id (the id is probably the row number of the contacts table)

Comment: When do we use ContactsContract.Contact and when do we use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone ?

Comment: Both the codes are working. It's just a problem with Eclipse.

Comment: I think that ContactContract.CommonDataKinds helps you to insert new data or change it(programmaticaly..) and ContactsContract.Contact just return the Contacts table as constant.. that way you'll can't change any data..

Comment: @VamsiChalla Correction!! don't pay attention to my first comment..  
ContactContract.CommonDataKinds holds the contact data like: 
photo, number,email and all this kinds of data..
ContactContract.Contacts holds the contactId, his name as it's displayd on your phone.. so when you want to get the phone number user the commonDataKinds.. else if you want to insert,update,remove contact or just select the contact displayed name use ContactContract.Contact

Comment: I am using gingerbread mobile and the above code is not showing sim contacts only contacts saved in phone is shown is it a bug or i need to use another method for gingerbread